# How to send file from Nodejs to Flask Python?

Tags: python, node.js, flask

Hope you are doing well.
I'm trying to send  pdfs file from **Nodejs** to **Flask** using Axios.
I read files from a directory (in the form of buffer array) and add them into formData (an npm package) and send an Axios request.

```
 const existingFile = fs.readFileSync(path)                                
    console.log(existingFile)
    const formData = new nodeFormData()
    formData.append("file", existingFile)
    formData.append("fileName", documentData.docuName)
    try {
         const getFile = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/pdf-slicer", formData,
                        {
                          headers: {
                                      ...formData.getHeaders()
                                   }
                           })
         console.log(getFile)} catch (e) {console.log(e, "getFileError")}
```

**On flask side:**

I'm trying to get data from the request.

```
    print(request.files)
    
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        file=request.form["file"]
        if file:
            print(file)
```

in **request.file**, I'm getting **ImmutableMultiDict([])**

but in **request.form["file"]**, I'm getting data something like this:

[image: request.form["file"] print example]

how can I handle this type of file format or how can I convert this file format to python fileObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by updating my **Nodejs** code.
We need to convert formData file into **octet/stream** format.

so I did minor change in my formData code :

before: `formData.append("file", existingFile)`

after: `formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream(existingFile)`

> Note: **fs.createReadStream** only accepts string or uint8array
> without null bytes. we cannot pass the buffer array.